# Unable to run meteor from Webstorm

Tags: meteor, webstorm

I want to run the meteor application from some IDE so that I can debug the server side code. 
For now I have setup the meteor application on the Webstorm. When I try to run the application I get following error message . Really appreciate your help.

> /Users/jackal/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.35.mewx50++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/lib/node_modules/fibers/future.js:173
>                         throw(ex);
>                               ^ Error: EACCES, permission denied '/Users/jackal/rschtml5/ageroRSCHTML/.meteor/local/build'
>       at Object.fs.renameSync (fs.js:548:18)
>       at Object.files.renameDirAlmostAtomically (/Users/jackal/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.35.mewx50++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.osx.x86_64/tools/files.js:644:8)
>       at _.extend.complete (/Users/jackal/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.35.mewx50++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.osx.x86_64/tools/builder.js:485:11)
>       at writeSiteArchive (/Users/jackal/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.35.mewx50++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.osx.x86_64/tools/bundler.js:1836:13)
>       at /Users/jackal/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.35.mewx50++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.osx.x86_64/tools/bundler.js:2206:20
>       at /Users/jackal/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.35.mewx50++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.osx.x86_64/tools/buildmessage.js:250:13
>       at _.extend.withValue (/Users/jackal/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.35.mewx50++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.osx.x86_64/tools/fiber-helpers.js:112:14)
>       at /Users/jackal/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.35.mewx50++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.osx.x86_64/tools/buildmessage.js:243:29
>       at _.extend.withValue (/Users/jackal/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.35.mewx50++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.osx.x86_64/tools/fiber-helpers.js:112:14)
>       at /Users/jackal/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.35.mewx50++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.osx.x86_64/tools/buildmessage.js:241:18
>       at _.extend.withValue (/Users/jackal/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.35.mewx50++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.osx.x86_64/tools/fiber-helpers.js:112:14)
>       at /Users/jackal/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.35.mewx50++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.osx.x86_64/tools/buildmessage.js:232:23
>       at _.extend.withValue (/Users/jackal/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.35.mewx50++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.osx.x86_64/tools/fiber-helpers.js:112:14)
>       at Object.capture (/Users/jackal/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.35.mewx50++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.osx.x86_64/tools/buildmessage.js:231:19)
>       at Object.exports.bundle (/Users/jackal/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.35.mewx50++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.osx.x86_64/tools/bundler.js:1926:31)
>       at bundleApp (/Users/jackal/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.35.mewx50++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.osx.x86_64/tools/run-app.js:509:28)
>       at _.extend._runOnce (/Users/jackal/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.35.mewx50++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.osx.x86_64/tools/run-app.js:527:24)
>       at _.extend._fiber (/Users/jackal/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.35.mewx50++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.osx.x86_64/tools/run-app.js:744:28)
>       at /Users/jackal/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.35.mewx50++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.osx.x86_64/tools/run-app.js:380:12

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about my answer for your specific scenario: I had a similar problem and the cause was the `npm` permissions, I had to run meteor as root: `sudo meteor`

I see in your paste: `Error: EACCES, permission denied '/Users/jackal/rschtml5/ageroRSCHTML/.meteor/local/build' at Object.fs.renameSync`

Some permission is wrong. I usually use the terminal in WebStorm, not the built-in build and run. Probably you haven't noticed because you're root. Try to create a new user and run `meteor create testProject`. I had this issue on my Meteor install.

Edit:
Check if any of these links solves your problems:

- https://github.com/oortcloud/meteorite/blob/master/README.md#permission-woes
- https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/893

Comment: sudo /Applications/WebStorm/app/Contents/MacOS/WebStorm

Comment: Mario,When I am creating a new project / sample projects from meteor through webstorm then I am able to run the application but I am unable to run the existing application using webstorm. When I try to run I am getting the above errors.